# Access DB in Java and .Net

Tags: java, .net, jdbc

I was wondering why there are so many technologies to access DB in .Net, including ADO.net, OLE DB, ODBC etc. In the modern world now, It is commonly to use OR mapping framework like Entity Framework, Nhibernate etc.

But In Java world , There only exist one API to access DB. It is called JDBC. It is simple and enough. It is well appreciated.

So I was thinking Is there any possibility to intercept the behavior of accessing DB in .Net world No matter what technology has been used. So I can inject some code before or after them. thanks!

Comment: Because every body thinks they have a better idea. And while there are agreed upon standards, not every body follows them fully or interprets them the same way.  Also, not every problem is a nail.

Comment: @MadProgrammer In my opinion, One unified standards to follow is simple and better than the multiple ones. thanks.

Comment: JDBC is not only way. You can use ODBC.

Comment: @Joe.wang No argument from me :P

Comment: @MasudCSECUET The API is the same one . not changed. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you have also many different technologies: JDBC, Hibernate, JDO, JPA to name only the most popular.

The main difference between Java and .NET is that in Java everything (except JDBC) is an external library whereas is .NET all technologies are bundled with the SDK.

Therefore it looks like .NET has many different technologies. Basically the different technologies are only evolutions...

Comment: I have to correct myself, I would have said Only one API for Java. and you are right, Microsoft technologies always bind with the SDK. The worst things of it is there would be different API for different technologies. This is the bad thing for developer. thanks!

Comment: Hi, I can't understood your last sentence well. It is appreciated if you can tell me more about it .thanks!

Comment: @Joe.wang As in Java Hibernate enhanced the JDBC interface the different technologies in .NET enhance the previous technology one by one while including easier to understand constructs.

Comment: But I think the API is totally changed as the version upgrade in .NET. But Java didn't .